# Codeigniter + MongoDb : where_in is returning all object(s) of an array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, codeigniter

I am using bcit-ci Codeigniter's library for MongoDb, the codeigniter version 3.1 and MongoDb 3.2, having problem in retrieving only one index of array. The where_in is returning the whole array containing object(s).
Here's the data structure :
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GeGK.png)

I want to get only one object according to the id match.
below is the query i written :

```
$this->mongo_db->select(['email_templates']);
$this->mongo_db->where('_id', new MongoId($vendor_id));
$this->mongo_db->where_in('email_templates.id', [$id]);
$query = $this->mongo_db->get('vendor');
```

this query is giving the whole array of object(s).
I just want the single object which exactly matches the condition.

Comment: dear @Neil, working on mongodb with codeigniter and working with codeigniter is too different. The reference you given is not relevant to what i am asking.

Comment: Show that you tried it in your question. You only need to add one line. But I'm guessing you simply did not read the linked answer.

Comment: when i use row() and row()->field , it says that  Call to a member function row() on array.